# Python Django - template not displaying properly in browser

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

The following is my actual code of section in my page. Its displaying properly while directly called from the html. While using a template its not working. The alignment of the entire page is getting changed.

The following is the actual html code (Still made it small):

```
   <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse06">
                                        <i class="switch fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        Office Help Desk
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                     </div>   
            </div>
```

While I am trying to use it a template the entire alignment is getting changed. The following is the html file i am using to call the template (Trying to give 'Office Help Desk' to the template):

```
{% extends 'career_page/layout_new.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
     Office Help Desk           
{% endblock %}
```

I added the the block content tag to the main html file and is as follows:

```
<div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse06">
                                    <i class="switch fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                 </div>   
        </div>
```

The entire alignment is getting changed, while trying to open the actual html file its working fine. What might be the problem. Please help me with this. I am new to Django.

Actual html page
[image: actual page]

After using template
[image: after using template]

Comment: What does "the entire alignment is getting changed" mean?

Comment: The code you add to the template isn't the same one in the first snippet, its missing some tags. Please try to create an [mcve]

Comment: @DanielRoseman The entire header is getting misaligned (height is getting increased). I dont know how. Whereas its working fine as a normal html, when I try to use it as a template something is going wrong. Please help

Comment: @Sayse I have modified the code, I was just trying to give the text 'Office Help Desk' to the template, but the alignment got changed. Please help

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the images, please help

Comment: Are you using any static files?